# How can I remove the shadows from the unity panel?

Tags: unity, compiz, panel

Last update brought shadows to the Unity panel - or at least I just noticed them.

I know that I can remove any shadows I want through the *Window Decoration* plugin in *ccsm* but grabbing the panel doesn't give me its name.

So, what do I have to add to the *Shadow Windows* rule to remove the Unity panel shadows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### For 11.04 and 11.10:

Replace `/usr/share/unity/3/panel-shadow.png` with an invisible image.

Comment: Do you mean that the panel uses an image for the shadow instead of compiz's shadows?!
Is there any reason that they chose it to be this way?

Comment: Yes, currently it's just an image (as it was in 10.10). I assume it's due to a lack of resources (namely time). Adding bling is usually not the top priority, but development doesn't stop with Natty Narwhal, so this probably will change in the future. ;-)

Comment: Just renaming it also seems to work :)

Answer (score 6):

#### For 14.04 and above:

Replace image `/usr/share/unity/icons/panel-shadow.png` with transparent png image.

Better way to find shadow in future revisions is `locate panel-shadow.png` in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

#### For 12.04:

The relevant file is now at:

```
/usr/share/unity/5/panel-shadow.png
```

You can delete it, you can rename it, or you can back up the original image and used Gimp's eraser to make the image transparent (just erase the whole thing).

If Unity can't find it, it won' t complain (or show it to you).

Keep in mind that whenever Unity is updated, it will replace the shadow image file, and you'll have to repeat your fix accordingly. If you find yourself forgetting what file it is you modified (or where it lives) you can try renaming it to something more memorable, like `annoying-panel-shadow.png`. Then you can just type `$ locate annoying` and quickly find the right folder and file to update.