# How to customize window shadow in Ubuntu without disabling Unity?

Tags: 15.04, compiz, 15.10, 14.10, window-decoration

I have tried everything but none of it seems to work. When I use window decorator in Compiz toolkit, it disables Unity and I don't want it to be disabled. So can you tell me how can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the shadows from the unity panel?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33320/how-can-i-remove-the-shadows-from-the-unity-panel)